# Calculating the limit of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is $lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow(\infty, \infty)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$?

I want to know $\frac{1}{x^2-y^2}$ tends to zero faster than $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ or not?

I draw $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$ in maple and seems that $lim _{(x,y) \rightarrow(\infty, \infty)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is not exist.
If $y=kx$,then
$$
lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(\infty, \infty)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}=lim_{x \rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^2+(kx)^2}{x^2-(kx)^2}=\frac{1+k^2}{1-k^2}
$$
So,the limit depends on $k$,hence the limit is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try various directions.  All the limits you get have to be the same value. Otherwise there is no limit.
If you go along the line $x=2y$ to infinity, what is the limit?
If you go along the $x$-axis to infinity, what is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the limits on the lines $x=2y$, and $x=3y$.